# JSON.net not finding property value when property exists

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm working with Json.net, I have retrieved the following JSON from a web page:

```
"{\"Response\":
    [{
    \"iconPath\":\"",
    \"membershipType\":1,
    \"membershipId\":\"124877458474\",
    \"displayName\":\"DarylJG\"
    }],

    \"ErrorCode\":1,
    \"ThrottleSeconds\":0,
    \"ErrorStatus\":\"Success\",
    \"Message\":\"Ok\",
    \"MessageData\":{ }}"
```

Now, I'm getting the following error when trying to return a string from this property:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain
>   a definition for 'iconPath'

Which the iconPath does exist within this JSON file. The code i'm using:

```
var response = client.GetAsync("CorrectServerPath & Auth").Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
dynamic item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);


return item.Response.iconPath;
```

This is the lines of code which are throwing this error, but the following code:

```
return item.Message;
```

will return *OK*

So my overall question, is how can I reach *iconPath* in the provided json file using JSON.net? As, i'm at a loss. Research material has come up with nothing & Probably using the incorrect Search Terms

Comment: Your `Response` member is an array, not an object. Try `item.Response[0].iconPath`

Comment: @CollinDauphinee That's a huge oversight. Would you prefer to as this to an answer so I can accept accordingly? Your recommendation has solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Response` member is an array, not an object. Use `item.Response[0].iconPath`, instead.